# How to do a quick search filter on key up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, optimization

I'm trying to add a filter functionality in a table with bunch of table data in it. Almost 800 `td`.

I can able to search the text when typing in the input but my logic is very slow. It is not allowing me to write the text fully before it searches, kind of stucking in the text input.

So i'm looking for a help to find what is wrong in this code. How to optimize this? Can any one help me.

Here is the CODE

```
jQuery("#sear").keyup(function(){
var searching_val = jQuery(this).val();
var mysearch = new RegExp(searching_val,'gi'); 
jQuery("#container td").each(function(){
if(mysearch.test(jQuery(this).data('samp'))){
    jQuery(this).show();
}else{
    jQuery(this).fadeOut();
}
   });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m74bvsdo/)

The example i shown in fiddle is having only two rows. In Real i have More `Rows` with More `Table Data`.

Is this is common behaviour when we have more `td`? Or Is there a way to optimize this? I cannot avoid looping through `<td>` `data-samp` attribute too because content are different format, those are not as seen in sample. So all those are store in data attribute of a table `td` to retrieve it for input.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that works for you:

```
jQuery("#sear").keyup(function(e){
    var searching_val = jQuery(this).val();
    setTimeout(function(){
       if(searching_val != ""){  // If search value is not empty value
          jQuery("#container td").show();
          jQuery("#container td").each(function(){
              if(jQuery(this).text().indexOf(searching_val) < 0){
                  jQuery(this).hide();
              }
          });
       }else{
          jQuery("#container td").show();  // Show all td's
       }
    }, 2000);
});
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks +1 for your help. i used your solution with `jQuery(this).data('samp')` instead of `jQuery(this).text()` but still i can't able to type continuously, the text input is hanging. I'm having more td in real

Comment: I have updated the code, so now you can perform by pressing enter key after entering your search value. Enjoy..!!

Comment: What might be the problem? I don't want them to press enter.

Comment: Let me know how exactly you want to perform search, so that i will update the answer as per.

Comment: When user start typing they need to see the result without waiting. Right now i can't even type remaining letters when i typed one or two characters. It is making us to wait to type remaining letters after it shows for the first letter i typed. It is hanging the input text to type

Comment: I have updated the code with few changes to work for your without hanging. Check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59882/discussion-between-rram-and-viswanath-d).